# Change ngModel value after put response

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable called dummy_value and i want to change it with an input box.

```
<p>{{dummy_value}}</p>
<input [(ngModel)]="dummy_value" />
```

When i do this, dummy_value updates immediately because of two binding.
But i want to change it after API response without defining extra variable.

```
public changeInput() {
   this.my_service.changeInput(this.dummy_value)
      .then(response => {
        // change here.
      }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do something like this: `this.dummy_value = response.data.whatever;` ?

Comment: You can set a ViewChild property on your html and the access it through  nativeElement in your component

Comment: @obey yeah, but the problem is whenever i write or delete something from input box, the p tag value also changes before sending request.

Comment: if you are using the same scope variable for <p> and <input> tags, since ngModel is two way data binding, i don't think there is a way of accomplishing what you are trying. I can suggest that you updating your <p> tag as following : <p>{{updated_dummy_value}}</p> and inside of your .then(), you can set scope.updated_dummy_value="new value".

Comment: @Caner Akdeniz thanks i was using it like your said but the answer below is what i was looking for. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the two-way data binding and use a `@ViewChild` decorator:

```
<p>{{dummy_value}}</p>
<input #myname [ngModel]="dummy_value" />
```

---

```
@ViewChild('myname') input: ElementRef;
public changeInput() {
   this.my_service.changeInput(this.dummy_value)
      .then(response => {
        this.dummy_value = this.input.nativeElement.value;
      }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cbcuj)

Comment: Thank you, i was looking something like this.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: i will, but i have to wait 2 more minutes to mark it.